# ChartJS how to improve mobile tap areas

Tags: chart.js

Some of my users have mentioned that its hard to tap a chart point to see its tooltip data. Is there a way to increase the area of clickable points?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [pointHitRadius](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/charts/line.html#point-styling) to a higher number:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        pointHitRadius: 25
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        pointHitRadius: 25
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.0/chart.umd.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```